# On-demand resources direct access

Tags: ios9, xcode7, on-demand-resources

Can anyone help? After downloading the some needed asset pack, ios put him into internal "AssetPack" directory. Can I get direct access to MY(loaded) files located in this directory? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

It can be accessed with [NSBundle pathForResource:ofType:], what return full path for downloaded resources.